# How do I get the the position of the control relative to the screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I try to use the following method:

`UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;`

`CGRect rect = [button convertRect:button.bounds toView:window];`

But it still gets a frame relative to the parent view(headerView). You can see in code image.

What should I do to get the position of the control relative to the screen？

[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrMAE.png)

Comment: You used origin `(10, 10)` relative to header view and then you got output `(20, 20)` on the image you posted. It seems that it works then. What is your expected result? Anyway, I believe you could use `nil` instead of key window when trying to get coordinates relative to screen.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The headerview is loaded in the center of the screen, and the button is loaded on the headerview. The rect I want to get is the frame of the button relative to the screen. So output should be something like (200, 400) (assuming the screen size is 400x800).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the cause of your result is a deprecation of `keyWindow`. Try the following:

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.firstObject;
```

The code you had returns a `null` value for key window. I am still confused why this method returns the coordinates you receive. I have tried it and it does not return coordinates I would expect from Apple documentation:

> If view is nil, this method instead converts to window base
> coordinates. Otherwise, both view and the receiver must belong to the
> same UIWindow object.